# css transform without overwriting previous transform?

Tags: css, transform

I have an element:

```
elem
   transform translateY(5px) scale(1.2)
```

Now on hover I want it to move down an additional 5px

```
elem:hover
   transform translateY(5px)
```

Obviously this would overwrite the previous transform. Is there anyway to set it to move an additional 5 without knowing what the previous transform state is?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be cool to have something like `#elem:hover { transform: add translateY(5px); }`. Unfortunately, such a thing doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Since Chrome 104 there are [individual transform properties](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-transforms-2/#individual-transforms) such as `scale: 1.5; rotate: 45deg; translate: -50%;` etc. But, as of 17.03.2023 they have only [88% support on CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_translate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CSS custom properties aka CSS variables are the only answer to this (outside of using Javascript).

To add to a previous value:

```
div {
  --translateX: 140;
  --trans: calc(var(--translateX) * 1px);
  transform: translateX(var(--trans)) scale(1.5);
}

div:hover {
  
 --translatemore: calc(var(--translateX) + 25);
 --trans: calc(var(--translatemore) * 1px);
}

div {
  transition: .2s transform;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: salmon;
}
```

All browsers now support the ability to set transform properties individually.

- https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_translate
- https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_scale

Answer (score 4):

Use the WebKitCSSMatrix object or MozCSSMatrix (I think...) to set new values trough the original object without knowing the initial transform.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cx9hH/

In this case I have an initial translate of 100px on witch I add an extra 100px:

```
box.style.webkitTransform = matrix.translate(100, 0);
```

Comment: Nice, this doesn't cover all the cases but +upvote for being potentially useful for somebody.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to create another div or span wrapper and set transform to that intead

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30219714)

Comment: @GhostOps this is a legit answer dude.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use nested elements, and increase the translation on each on interdependently for each variable.

Although, that would get ugly pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

CSS variables!
https://jsfiddle.net/91q0s5h0/4/

```
div {
  --translateX: 10px;
  transform: translateX(var(--translateX)) scale(1.5);
}

div:hover {
  --translateX: 5px;
}
```

Comment: as far as I can tell this does not work, it replaces the 10px with the 5px instead of adding onto it.

Comment: Also, these variables are still set in stone, and won't change dynamically when changing the translation through javascript.