# css animation on fixed and centred element jump about when animating

Tags: css, sass

I have a fixed element that it centered like this

```css
.cen-div
  position: fixed!important
  top: 50%!important
  right: 50%!important
  transform: translate(50%, -50%)!important
```

then I have a keyframe animation that scales the element.

```
.modal-animation
  animation: ping-open ease-in-out
  animation-duration: .25s
  animation-iteration-count: 1

@keyframes ping-open
  0%
    transform: scale(.95)
  100%
    transform: scale(1)
```

When it plays the element jumps to a different position then finally rests back to its correct and original place.

Does any one know why?

Comment: PS avoid the use of `!important`.

Comment: The html is irrelevant? Its a fixed element so out of the normal flow of the dom? no? But either way its a <div> right after the closing </head>

Comment: your `transform`  is being overwritten. Use other means of centering an element. Create a [mcve] so I can get a *"picture"* and provide a solution depending on what you're building.

Comment: ok sure ill do a code pen

Comment: Otherwise it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890948/css-transform-without-overwriting-previous-transform and many other similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

add `translate(50%, -50%)` also to animation keyframes

```
@keyframes ping-open
  0%
    transform: translate(50%, -50%) scale(.95)
  100%
    transform: translate(50%, -50%) scale(1)
```